# Im trying to use a click function which uses 'this' as to get the value after the last '/' in the URL by using split('/') or lastindexof('/')

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am triggering a click() function which will grab the users url link from an anchor tag and then I am trying to grab the end part of the URL which contains the username.

I can do this with out using $(this) but this has become a requirement and I need it done this way.

Please see the snippet to better understand.

```js
$('a[href]').click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  var test = this;

  // works fine
  alert(test)

  // doesn't work
  alert(test.substring(test.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <p>
    I need to get the end part of the URL(john)
  </p>
</div>

<a href="https://www.blah.com/john">click here</a>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`this` will be a reference to the DOM element, the anchor, not to the anchor's `href` property.

Try `var test = this.href;`

```js
$('a[href]').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var test = this.href;

  // doesn't work
  alert(test.substring(test.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <p>
    I need to get the end part of the URL(john)
  </p>
</div>

<a href="https://www.blah.com/john">click here</a>
```

Comment: Dude it worked, you have answered a number of my questions, why don't you just give me a direct line so I can call anytime I need something. )p Thanks heaps

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:-

```js
$('a[href]').click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  var test = this;

  // works fine
  alert(test.href)   // use `test.href` instead of just `test`

  // works fine now
  alert(test.href.substring(test.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <p>
    I need to get the end part of the URL(john)
  </p>
</div>

<a href="https://www.blah.com/john">click here</a>
```

Comment: Thanks @palash, awesome stuff

Answer (score 0):

The error is because test is the html 'a' element and not the url itself. Use test.href to access the url string.

Replace the javascript with:

```
$('a[href]').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = this.href;

  alert(url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
})
```

Refer the jsfiddle here for a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/aditiraveesh/s0bauby4/).